# Microsoft.SqlServer.Management Smo Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a asp.net project which is runing on .Net Framework 2.0 with Visual Studio 2008.
Everything is working smoothly. Now I want to change Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2010.
When I build the project in Visual Studio 2010 and .Net Framework 2.0 I get the error like:

The type or namespace name 'Smo' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

How can I solve this problem?

My Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll versions is 10.0.0.0 and Runtime version is v2.0.50727.

Comment: Did you manually add there reference to the project..? if it's backwards compatible then you need to select that .DLL if not then you need to find the version that works in `vs2010` also check to see if you are building the project as 2.0 and not 4.0

Answer (score 0):

**In short:** I would go ahead, and make sure that the migrated project is targeting the right framework version. In your case it is .NET 2.0. That might be something that your project is missing in project configuration/properties.

By default any migrated project in VS environment targets the default framework of new IDE. In your specific case, i belief it is targeting NET 4.0. Just change it.

**Edit:** This issue is related to direct dependency of Smo to .NET 3.5. Here you are more detailed post in Microsoft forum - [Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo could not be resolved](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/651546/microsoft-sqlserver-smo-could-not-be-resolved-because-it-has-an-indirect-dependency-on-the-framework-assembly-system-core-version-3-5-0-0).

Comment: I checked my prject and I can see the .Net 2.0 in target place.

Comment: what does your log files says? there should be other related error logs beside this one

Comment: Check all your references, there should be some warnings?

Comment: I checked all references and there is not any problem about it. :(

Comment: Did you tried to `Clean Solution` and then `Rebuild` the solution